# Java Web server display images from file system?

Tags: java, tomcat, web, visualization, data-visualization

I am developing a web application which collects data every day and shows data visualisation images on the web pages.My web server is Tomcat. Now it can collect data and import data into MySQL. Then it generates visualisation images based on the given data using [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) library and exports the images to local file system. For example I export the images to folders like "C:/hdsdata/2016-01-01/".
But I don't know how to display the generated images on the web pages. I can only show visualisation images under the war directory not a file system directory. Or I don't know how to export visualisation images to the war directory.

Comment: when you call `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsXXXX()` ex, `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG()` first param is File object, set the path of file to `<tomcat-path>/webapps/<your-webapp-path>/charts/file_name.png` then it will be saved in your webapp path

Comment: `.../charts/` can be any other folder name you can create in your webapp folder

Comment: What is your Tomcat version?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz It's 7.0.59

Answer (score 1):

It's a mistake to write files into your web application's deployment directory: if you undeploy the application, Tomcat will delete everything, removing all those files.

Instead, have a look at Tomcat's [`aliases` attribute](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) on the `<Context>` element in your web application's `context.xml` file.

You can use this to map paths external to your application into the URL space of your application. For example, if your files are being written to `/home/images/charts/[whatever].jpg` you could configure your `aliases` like this:

```
<Context aliases="/images=/home/images/charts">
```

This will protect your files from being deleted when you undeploy the context. You can also store the on a network fileshare or somewhere more convenient than in the web application's deployment directory.